# How to read a list from a txt as it is in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to load the content of a txt file in in a python concept in order to use it for training my model in svm. 
I would like to load the data as they are on my txt file:

```
[ 0.02713807  0.01802697  0.01690036  0.01501216  0.01466412  0.01638859       0.0210163   0.02658022  0.03664452  0.05064286  0.06027664  0.06431134       0.04303673  0.03247764  0.02293602  0.01847688  0.0174582   0.01860664       0.02576164  0.02296149  0.0582211   0.37246149]
[ 0.03623561  0.05211099  0.02469929  0.0134991   0.01029103  0.00880611       0.00898548  0.00870684  0.0117465   0.01962223  0.03895351  0.01956952      0.00972828  0.00704872  0.00656471  0.00689743  0.00854528  0.01128713      0.02119957  0.05047751  0.05028719  0.57473797]
```

And the code that I am using is the one below:

```
data = []
with open('data2.txt') as f:
  for y in f:
    data.append(float(y.strip()))
    print (data)
```

When I am running my script I am getting this error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[ 0.02713807  0.01802697  0.01690036  0.01501216  0.01466412  0.01638859'

How should I solve this, any advice please?

Comment: So, your text file has "[" and "]"? and there are no commas between the values?

Comment: Yes, @InAFlash, there are no commas and I ma using []. Each one of these arrays are the extracted features of an image, therefore I am using "[" and "]".

Comment: so, each list in the text file is in a separate line? or extended over multiple lines like shown in the text

Comment: The lines are read in as strings, so you need to convert them to `list` not `float`.

Comment: @berkelem, thats not the problem, he's already doing it. its because of multiple values separated by spaces

Comment: @berkelem should I do this with 
>>>import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(y)

instead of data.append(float(y.strip()))
?

Comment: @InAFlash, yes each list is in a separate line, I will correct this in the question.

Comment: The real question is: why do you have this file? Did you generate it by calling `str` on some NumPy arrays and writing the result to a file or something? If so, can you change your code to not do that, and instead write something that's actually meant to be parsed, like JSON or `np.savetxt`?

Comment: @abarnert I have used np.savetxt to save this array. This is an array of features extracted by images, which I want to use in order to train my svm.

Comment: If you used `np.savetxt`, why aren't you loading it back with NumPy?

Comment: Absolutely, use `np.loadtxt()`

Comment: The thing is, this isn't the default format for `np.savetxt`, so… whatever you did to make it look like this, you have to pass the equivalent arguments to `loadtxt`. (Or, more simply, just `savetxt` with the default arguments, and then you can `loadtxt` with the default arguments…)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

How about this:

```
data = []
with open('data2.txt') as f:
  for l in f:
    data.append(list(map(float,l[1:-2].split())))
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[[0.02713807, 0.01802697, 0.01690036, 0.01501216, 0.01466412, 0.01638859, 0.0210163, 0.02658022, 0.03664452, 0.05064286, 0.06027664, 0.06431134, 0.04303673, 0.03247764, 0.02293602, 0.01847688, 0.0174582, 0.01860664, 0.02576164, 0.02296149, 0.0582211, 0.37246149], [0.03623561, 0.05211099, 0.02469929, 0.0134991, 0.01029103, 0.00880611, 0.00898548, 0.00870684, 0.0117465, 0.01962223, 0.03895351, 0.01956952, 0.00972828, 0.00704872, 0.00656471, 0.00689743, 0.00854528, 0.01128713, 0.02119957, 0.05047751, 0.05028719, 0.5747379]]
```

If you want list of NumPy arrays do:

```
import numpy as np
data = []
with open('data2.txt') as f:
  for l in f:
    data.append(np.array(list(map(float,l[1:-2].split()))))
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[array([ 0.02713807,  0.01802697,  0.01690036,  0.01501216,  0.01466412,
        0.01638859,  0.0210163 ,  0.02658022,  0.03664452,  0.05064286,
        0.06027664,  0.06431134,  0.04303673,  0.03247764,  0.02293602,
        0.01847688,  0.0174582 ,  0.01860664,  0.02576164,  0.02296149,
        0.0582211 ,  0.37246149]), array([ 0.03623561,  0.05211099,  0.02469929,  0.0134991 ,  0.01029103,
        0.00880611,  0.00898548,  0.00870684,  0.0117465 ,  0.01962223,
        0.03895351,  0.01956952,  0.00972828,  0.00704872,  0.00656471,
        0.00689743,  0.00854528,  0.01128713,  0.02119957,  0.05047751,
        0.05028719,  0.5747379 ])]
```

Comment: 1. never call a variable `l` -- that's the way to disaster and a great pain for people who read your code. 2. instead of `l[1:-2].split()` you should use `l.split()[1:-1]` -- split into the parts first, then remove leading and trailing brackets, because you may never know how many trailing spaces do these lines have.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression to retrieve numbers from line:

```
data = []

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        numbers = re.search(r'\[\s*(.*\d)\s*\]', line).group(1)
        data.append(list(map(float, numbers.split())))

print(data)
```

**Output**:

```
[[0.02713807, 0.01802697, 0.01690036, 0.01501216, 0.01466412, 0.01638859, 0.0210163, 0.02658022, 0.03664452, 0.05064286, 0.06027664, 0.06431134, 0.04303673, 0.03247764, 0.02293602, 0.01847688, 0.0174582, 0.01860664, 0.02576164, 0.02296149, 0.0582211, 0.37246149], [0.03623561, 0.05211099, 0.02469929, 0.0134991, 0.01029103, 0.00880611, 0.00898548, 0.00870684, 0.0117465, 0.01962223, 0.03895351, 0.01956952, 0.00972828, 0.00704872, 0.00656471, 0.00689743, 0.00854528, 0.01128713, 0.02119957, 0.05047751, 0.05028719, 0.57473797]]
```

Answer (score 0):

- split the line
- replace the dot by empty string
- check if it is a number

```py
data = []
with open('./data.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
      data.append([y for y in l.split() if y.replace('.','',1).isdigit()])
      print (data)
```

output

```
[['0.02713807', '0.01802697', '0.01690036', '0.01501216', '0.01466412'], ['0.03623561', '0.05211099', '0.02469929', '0.0134991', '0.01029103']]
```

Comment: Could you explain why please? The OP wants to read each line and append the corresponding list into data. Did I get it wrong ?

Comment: I tested the code and i saw that the output gives the decimals one by one (the decimals are inside on of the decimals in the txt file)

Answer (score 0):

If you generated this file with [`np.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html), the obvious way to load is it [`np.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

More generally, you should never just save stuff to a file in "whatever format, I don't care" and then beat your head against the wall trying to figure out how to parse that format. Save stuff in a format you know how to load. Use `np.savetxt` and you can load it with `np.loadtxt`; `np.save` and `np.load`; `json.dump` and `json.load`; `pickle.dump` and `pickle.load`; `csv.writer` and `csv.reader`… they come in matched pairs for a reason. (What about formats like just appending `str(row)` to a file? There *is* no function that reads that. So the answer is: don't do that.)

And then, the whole problem of "how do I parse something that looks like the repr of a list of floats but with the commas all removed" never arises in the first place.

I'm not sure how you can actually get output that looks like that out of `savetxt`. By default, if you write a 2D array to a file, you get columns separated by a single space, not blocks of columns with extra space between the blocks, and you don't get brackets around each row. There are a zillion arguments to control the format in different ways, but I have no idea what combination of arguments would give you that format.

But presumably, *you* know what you called. So you can pass the equivalent arguments to `loadtxt`.

Or, ideally, make things simpler: change your code to just call `savetxt` with the default arguments in the first place.

Comment: @T.ksaps Well, you're loading a completely different file from the one you saved. That can't be good.

Comment: @T.ksaps Meanwhile, is there a reason for passing those arguments to `savetxt`? Sure, it should work, but why make things more complicated?

Comment: Sorry @abarnert, revising the comment
I have changed my savetxt according to your advice as np.savetxt("data2.txt",data,delimiter=',', fmt='%f') Though, when I am trying to loadtxt with the command data = np.loadtxt("data2.txt",dtype= float,delimiter=',') I receive the same error of the question. Any advice please?

Comment: @T.ksaps I don't see how you could get that error from that code. [Here it is, working on repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/LowestFruitfulBackticks). You've got something else wrong in some code or data that you haven't shown us, and I can't debug it without seeing it.

Comment: Even when I am changing the parameters in the savetxt line, the error of the question remains :/

Comment: @T.ksaps Then, again, you're doing something else wrong in some code or data that you haven't shown us, and I can't debug it without seeing it.

Comment: I found maybe the wrong on the code. Its on the script where I save the data I post the script below 

`desc = LocalBinaryPatterns(20, 4)
data = []
for imagePath in paths.list_images(args["training"]):
 image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
 gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 hist = desc.describe(gray)
 data.append(hist)
 B = np.array(data)
 np.savetxt("train.txt",B,delimiter=',') #, fmt='%f'`

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('my_file.txt', 'r+')
my_file_data = f.read()
f.close()
```

The above code opens 'my_file.txt' in read mode then stores the data it reads from my_file.txt in my_file_data and closes the file. The read function reads the whole file at once. You can use the following to read the file line by line and store it in a list:

```
f = open('my_file', 'r+')
lines = [line for line inf.readlines()]
f.close()
```